# Missing or incorrectly formatted device token payload while generating jwt in php for unique iOS device

Tags: php, devicecheck

I wanna generate code to identify unique iOS device with server side php code. unable to get the right response from api.

I'm getting 200 http response but getting "Missing or incorrectly formatted device token payload"

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use Zenstruck\JWT\Token;
use Zenstruck\JWT\Signer\OpenSSL\ECDSA\ES256;
use \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;


$deviceToken = (isset($_POST["deviceToken"]) ? $_POST["deviceToken"] : null);
$transId = (isset($_POST["transId"]) ? $_POST["transId"] : null);



function generateJWT($teamId1, $keyId1, $privateKeyFilePath1) {

    $tt = time();
    $payload = [
    "iss" => $teamId1,
    "iat" => $tt
    ];

    $header = [
    "alg" => "ES256",
    "kid" => $keyId1
    ];

    $token = new Token($payload, $header);

    return (string)$token->sign(new ES256(), $privateKeyFilePath1);
}

function postReq($url, $jwt, $bodyArray) {

    $body = json_encode($bodyArray);

    $header = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$jwt,
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body)
                    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);  //Post Fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $server_output;

}

$teamId = "####";
$keyId = "####";
$privateKeyFilePath = "AuthKey_4A34ER43.p8";

$jwt = generateJWT($teamId, $keyId, $privateKeyFilePath);

//    $body = [
//    "device_token" => $deviceToken,
//    "transaction_id" => $transId,
//    "timestamp" => ceil(microtime(true)*1000)
//    ];

$ttt = ceil(microtime(true)*1000);

$body = array('device_token' => $deviceToken,'timestamp' => $ttt,'transaction_id' => $transId);
//$body1 = json_encode($body);

$myjsonis = postReq("https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com/v1/query_two_bits", $jwt, $body);

//print_r($myjsonis);
echo $myjsonis;


?>
```

I expected the result "{"bit0":true,"bit1":false,"last_update_time":"2017-06"}" but getting the error "Missing or incorrectly formatted device token payload" with response code 200.

Comment: Just finished coding a devicecheck implementation. Pretty similar codes. The only minor difference is I'm not calculating Content-Length myself. Since you are getting 200 that means your JWT is good too. So the second thing I can think of is device token is really wrongly formatted, maybe gets cropped or changed before it reaches here...